# Join Nhibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, join

I have list with ids

```
List<int> listOfIds;
```

And I have a query with cars objects.

I would like to do something like this:

```
query = from e in query 
join b listOfIdson e.b.Id equals b
select e;
```

but then I get error:

```
Specified method is not supported.
```

I know that its possible to do that by Join method which is avaiable on my query, but I have no idea how to do this. I can run following Join methods on my query:

```
query.Join()
query.JoinGroup()
```

Thats all

Thanks for help

Comment: would `from e in query where listOfIds.Contains(e.b.Id) select e` produce the desired result ?

Comment: I have used Contains method at first, but there is maximum parameters = 2100 so I can not use Contains :(

Comment: If you leave out linq, and use Criteria, you may try to use the XmlIn trick to bypass the 2100 limit see http://ayende.com/blog/2583/nhibernates-xml-in ( and non broken link to XmlIn.cs http://code.google.com/p/hornget/source/browse/trunk/package_tree/frameworks/rhino.tools/rhino/patch/commons/Rhino.Commons.NHibernate/NHibernate/XmlIn.cs?spec=svn78&r=78 )

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with QueryOver ?

```
var results = session.QueryOver<Car>().AndRestrictionOn(x=> x.id).IsIn(listOfIds)
```

Comment: In fact,there is 2,100 hard limit on the number of parameters that can be passed. That seems to be the problem @Ellbar is trying to solve. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx